# RubyGems not updating or installing the lastest version of Rails 3.2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've tried running the following to update my version of Rails from version 3.2.6 to version 3.2.7 without success.

```
gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

-

```
gem install rails
# Output
# 1 gem installed
# Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.6...
# Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.6...
```

-

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.7
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 3.2.7) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

-

I have tried clearing my Rubygem cache and my source list follows

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
http://gems.github.com/
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
WD

Comment: In my sources I have only http://rubygems.org/, and Rails 3.2.7 installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks Denis but still no luck. I've tried removing all sources and just adding rubygems.org.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've now solved this issue.

As I already had the lastest version of Rubygems, I couldn't figure out why the installation was getting the previous version of Rails (3.2.6). Below are how I finally installed Rails 3.2.7.

```
# Remove all sources (clear the cache    
gem sources -c

# Remove sources
gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/
gem sources -rhttp://gems.github.com/

# Add source
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/

# Note: I changed the uri from HTTP to HTTPS

# Update source cache
gem sources -u
```

Now, I have Rails 3.2.7 installed.

Comment: Thank you, in my case trying to remove rubygems.org showed it wasnt even a record. So merely adding it let me update my gems!